# Spring roo with GWT : How to stop scaffolding generation?

Tags: gwt, spring-roo

I am trying Spring roo with GWT. To generate the basic structure I used gwt:setup which generated the initial scaffolding but after that I want to stop the scaffolding, particularly when I annotate my domain class with @RooEntity.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found is to rename the generated directory from gwt to something else. Than roo stops generating the scaffolding code when class is marked with RooEntity

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the @RooGwtMirroredFrom from the *Record files